# Understanding Opencart's loader workflow

Tags: php, classloader, opencart

I am trying to understand how OpenCart's code works. The following code is defined in `index.php` (file attached) in OpenCart's mysite.com/admin/ folder. Could you please explain what the following code actually does ? I would like to know how it actually works.

I also have attached `loader.php` and `registry.php` under their respective folder.

```
// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);
```

[link to mysite.com admin](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27899629/mysite.com.zip)  folder zip

Though the following question is not similar to my question but still it touches similar point: 
[Opencart meta title include store name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086942/opencart-meta-title-include-store-name)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Registry
$registry = new Registry(); // Loads registry class from /system/engine/registry.php

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry); // Loads Loader class from /system/engine/loader.php
$registry->set('load', $loader); // Assigns the class to the registry allowing global use in other classes that use the registry object
```

Comment: // Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry); // Loads Loader class from /system/engine/registry.php....Did u mean "Loads Loader class from /system/engine/loader.php instead of registry.php".

Answer (score 0):

Opencart's coding logic is MVC+L (Language) model.

Not for the latest version, but you can learn most of the details about workflow here ;
http://www.packtpub.com/article/opencart-layout-structure