# Adding Store name to meta title OpenCart 1.5.4

Tags: seo, metadata, opencart

I have a store setup, and the SEO seems fine in terms of ranking. However, one thing I notice is that OpenCart doesn't include the shop name in the meta title.

Is there any way to hard code this in without getting any extensions? Just any pointers would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086942/opencart-meta-title-include-store-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add it in by editing the `header.tpl` file in `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/`